# Filter in query itself [SQL] VS extracting the large data and then filtering while processing each row [nodejs]?

Tags: sql

Which one is better, filtering in query itself [SQL] or extracting the large data and then filtering while processing each row [nodejs]?

Comment: SQL is the way to go!

Comment: By checks, do you mean the conditions in the `WHERE` clause? In general it's best to filter in the SQL query but to get a better answer please provide more details about the data, the query and what you want to acheive.

Comment: Also bear in mind that relational databases are *built* for working with sets (and also have tools for optimising such work). Your query is essentially "please find a subset of this set (the contents of the entire table)  which match these conditions" which is *great* if you're a tool built for answering questions about sets. No so great if your only option is to work row-by-agonizing-row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will generally be more efficient in terms of processing and network traffic to put checks in SQL itself.

Consider a table with a million rows, and only one row satisfies the check.

- If the check is put at the query-level, the database will return only one row. The database can optimize the query execution to do the operation efficiently.
- If the check is put at the application-level, then all million rows will be returned, and each one needs to be checked to find the one relevant row. This will increase the network traffic and likely be slower than if done at the database-level.